# Use nsdictionary to compile the table

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

i've an array with a variable number of nsdictionary.

```
NSDictionary * name1 = @{@"name" : @"anthony",
                   @"born" : @(1989),
                   @"lives" : @(5)};

NSDictionary *name2 = @{@"name" : @"pietro",
                   @"born" : @(1982),
                   @"lives" : @(2)};


NSArray *people = @[anthony, pietro];
```

basically i need to populate the cells of my table with the name inside "name" in nsdictionary.
How can i do that?

Comment: And what's your code for your `UITableView`?

Comment: I need to know what needs to be entered into - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath to have the name of the cell.

Comment: `NSDictionary *data = [people objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; [cell textLabel setText:[data objectForKey:@"name"]];`?

Comment: ok your code works.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your code snippet that all your name dictionaries are in the array self.people.

```
NSString *nameForCell=((NSDictionary *)self.people[indexPath.row])[@"name"];
```